# Length is increased while reversing a string

Tags: c

I'm working through "The C Programming Language" and trying to reverse a C-style string. My understanding is that a string literal like "voldemort" is represented as a character array (each of which has size 1) of 9 characters followed by a null character:

```
v o l d e m o r t \0
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

My idea to reverse the string is to find the length and then use that to declare an array of the appropriate length and define it as the reverse keeping a null at the end.

```
t r o m e d l o v \0
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

However, in my reversed string the length is suddenly longer and I'm not having any luck figuring out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mystrlen(char s[]);
void reverse(char original[], char reversed[], int len);

int mystrlen(char s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

void reverse(char original[], char reversed[], int len) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        reversed[i] = original[len-i-1];
    }
}

int main() {
    int len;
    char test[] = "voldemort";
    len = mystrlen(test);
    char tset[len+1];
    reverse(test, tset, len);
    printf("Original: %s\n", test);
    printf("Original Length: %d\n", mystrlen(test)); // 9
    printf("Original Size: %lu\n\n", sizeof(test)); // 10

    printf("Reversed: %s\n", tset);
    printf("Reversed Length: %d\n", mystrlen(tset)); // 13 (expected: 9)
    printf("Reversed Size: %lu\n", sizeof(tset));  // 10
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's wizardry, using the name of "you know who"

Comment: Looks like you aren't doing anything about 0 terminating the reversed copy...

Comment: @codekaizer "he who must not be reversed"

Comment: @John3136 Doesn't the statement "char tset[len+1]" initialize the array to all zeros?

Comment: @DavidStevens C doesn't do any initialization unless you explicitly tell it to. (or, short answer: "no" ;-)

Comment: @DavidStevens No . in C programming the initialization must be done. Say the initial values for all the variables is garbage, if not initialized. But if you make the variable static, then the variable get initialized with zero at start.

Comment: If you want to init an array to zero, you could try [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/). Ultimately, an array is just a block of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you reverse the string need to `NUL` terminate

```
   void reverse(char original[], char reversed[], int len) {
        int i, c;
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            reversed[i] = original[len-i-1];
        }
        reversed[i] = '\0'; //this line required
    }
```

Output:

```
Original: voldemort
Original Length: 9
Original Size: 10

Reversed: tromedlov
Reversed Length: 9
Reversed Size: 10
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to zero terminate the `reversed` string:

```
void reverse(char original[], char reversed[], int len) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        reversed[i] = original[len-i-1];
    }
    reversed[len] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you didn't terminate the string with the null character. I just wanted to point out that you're lucky the program successfully runs at all, because without the terminator strlen() will start reading well into whatever garbage memory happened to be after the end of your string. This is memory that it should not be touching, and sooner or later you will land yourself a segmentation fault. In your case there just happened to be a null character in that garbage before the operating system noticed and killed your program.

Comment: Appreciate it. Leaving this here in case anyone else wonders what "garbage" means in this context: https://www.quora.com/What-do-you-mean-by-a-garbage-value-in-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not initialized char tset[len+1]; it may contain undefined values, and since you are not settgin the '\0' at the end it is showing random values. You probably need to change the reverse function to something like:

```
void reverse(char original[], char reversed[], int len) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        reversed[i] = original[len-i-1];
    }

    reversed[len]='\0';
}
```

or initialize the tsset with 0 values.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

the function: `reverse()` is failing to NUL terminate the reversed string, so the second call to `mystrlen()` continues to count characters until is finds some 'random' character that contains a '\0'

Since this 'random' character will be beyond the end of the `tset[]` array, the posted code contains undefined behavior.

Comment: Appreciate the extra info as to why mystrlen() was overcounting :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add **'\0'** character to indecate the end of the string.

the new reverse function ->

```
void reverse(char original[], char reversed[], int len) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        reversed[i] = original[len-i-1];
    }
    reversed[len] = '\0';
}
```